# Inverse trignometric functions and Mean value theorem

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

[image: Question no.10]

[image: Mean value theorem form no.2 is to be used in this exercise]
[image: My work so far: I considered h(the quantity added is x being moved from 0 to x) and I used Le Hopital Rule in the limit]
I know my answer is wrong but I can't find my mistake or I don't have a profound understanding of the 2nd form of MVT. Can anyone guide me please

Comment: You should start posting with proper formatting; it is not such a big deal but if it doesn't take too much effort, why not use it.

Comment: You're right actually... I love tidiness but can you inform me how to do it? Like making the font mathematical or whatever it is called :)

Comment: Of course. Get started from [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Wow, i'll try using them in my new question. Thank you :)

Comment: Check this out: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2013570/357803

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MVT theorem states that there exists $\theta\in (0,1)$ such that

$$\arctan(x+h)-\arctan x=\dfrac{h}{1+\theta^2h^2}.$$

Now, if $x=0$ then we have

$$\arctan h-\arctan 0=\dfrac{h}{1+\theta^2h^2}.$$ Writing $h=x$ we have

$$\arctan x-\arctan 0=\dfrac{x}{1+\theta^2x^2}.$$ Since $\arctan 0=0$ it is

$$\arctan x=\dfrac{x}{1+\theta^2x^2}.$$ So

$$1+\theta^2x^2=\dfrac{x}{\arctan x}.$$ Thus

$$\theta^2=\dfrac{1}{x\arctan x}-\dfrac{1}{x^2}$$ or, equivalently

$$\theta=\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{x\arctan x}-\dfrac{1}{x^2}}.$$

Finally, you need to compute $$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{1}{x\arctan x}-\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{x-\arctan x}{x^2\arctan x}.$$

Comment: Mamma mia...magnificent... Formidable... excellent...loved your work...seriously talking... I ended up with the limit to an answer of sqrt(3)/3... and what you have said is perfectly nice... I think you forget the squaring of h in the first step...but it's ok... the idea lies in the concept :)... thanks alottttt

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice words. Where is it supossed I have omitted the squaring of $h?$

Comment: In the First step... the h in the denominator... instead of O^2×h, i think it shoud be O^2×h^2

Comment: Ohhhh....My badddd.... I didn't scroll to the right. I'm so sorryyyyy

Comment: Don't worry. These things happen.

Comment: If I just can send a pic in comments to show you how I saw it :(.... anyway, thank you sooooo muchhh