# A question in Rolle's and MVT theorem

Tags: functions

[image: No.21]
[image: My work so far]
So, I reached a deadline. I can't figure any more steps out. I just know that 
$f'(a)(x-a)>0$ but it doesn't make $f(x)>0$ !!  Could anyone give me a push?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. Let $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f(c)<0$.

i) By  MVT there is $t_1\in (a,c)$ such that 
$$f'(t_1)=\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}=\frac{f(c)}{c-a}<0.$$

ii) Again by MVT there is $t_2\in (c,b)$ such that 
$$f'(t_2)=\frac{f(b)-f(c)}{b-c}=-\frac{f(c)}{b-c}>0.$$

Now use MVT for $f'$ in the interval $(t_1,t_2)$ and get a contradiction.

P.S. As regards yurnero's comment I agree with him that the statement of the problem is a bit confusing. It is not clear if it is asking:

i) $(\forall x\in[a,b], f''(x)<0)\implies (f(x)\geq 0,\forall x\in[a,b])$.

or

ii) $\forall x\in[a,b]:(f''(x)<0)\implies (f(x)\geq 0)$.

We proved i) whereas ii) is false.
In fact, take $a=0$, $b=1$ and $f(x)=x^3-x^2$. Then $f(0)=f(1)=0$, $f''(x)=6x-2$, $f''(1/6)<0$ and $f(1/6)<0$.

Comment: Are you assuming $f''(x)<0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ or merely $f''(c)<0$?

Comment: @yurnero Since we do not know what is $c$, we have to assume that $f''(x)<0$ in $(a,b)$.

Comment: The question doesn't read like that to me. It seems to claim: $\forall x\in[a,b]:(f''(x)<0)\implies (f(x)\geq 0)$ whereas what you prove is $(\forall x\in[a,b], f''(x)<0)\implies (f(x)\geq 0,\forall x\in[a,b])$ .

Comment: Just to avoid potential confusion from my last comment, the way I read the problem, a proof by contradiction would assume both $f(c)<0$ and $f''(c)<0$ but without assuming $f''(x)<0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

Comment: @yurnero I see your point. The statement on the book is badly written. If you have $f(a)=f(b)=0$ and $f''(c)<0$ for some $c\in (a,b)$ then it does not follow that $f(c)\geq 0$.

Comment: @yurnero I edited my answer with a P.S. Does my P.S. answer your question?

Comment: Perfect answer. +1 and good day to you!

Comment: About your p.s.  :
The question recommend that f''(x) is always neagtive for every x in (a,b). Your example gives f''(x)=6x-2 which is not always negative.

Comment: I mean f''(0)=-2 <0

Comment: @Abed Shaar It is not clear  if $\forall x\in[a,b]:(f''(x)<0)\implies (f(x)\geq 0)$ or $(\forall x\in[a,b], f''(x)<0)\implies (f(x)\geq 0,\forall x\in[a,b])$. The two stataments are different. See the positions of the parenthesis (and yurnero comments).

Comment: Ohh...but I think thay meant by the second one...the second proposition

Comment: @Abed Shaar Now it is the first option. Yes I think this is the question, but  yurnero pointed out that in his opinion it was unclear. So my P.S.

Answer (score 0):

We cant say this ,if a function is positive at one end point then it is positive for all **[a,b]** .
Like:- take f(x)=-x^3 on [-2,4].

Comment: But in -x^3, $f''(x)$ is not always strictly negative as the question recommend. -x^3 concaves up over [-2,0] then concaves down over [0,4]